# How to obtain the older tweets from twitter in json format

Tags: json, twitter, twitter-oauth

Currently, i am using

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=<search term>
```

to obtain tweets from twitter. But, it returns only the recent tweets. How can i obtain the older tweets also in json format. Is this possible without using any twitter authentication key???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way to obtain the older tweet of a user by using twitter streaming API. But it is helpful in obtaining tweets for a specified user.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2
```